# Codeigniter DB_driver ERROR

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've just got this errors! Im new with codeigniter! i got the correct database, and all! but this errors i dont know what is this! Can you guys help me? thanks alot!

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\try\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php:92 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\try\system\database\DB_driver.php(116): CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect() 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\try\system\database\DB.php(149): CI_DB_driver->initialize() 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\try\system\core\Loader.php(347): DB(Array, NULL) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\try\application\controllers\Post.php(6): CI_Loader->database() 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\try\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(309): Post->__Construct() 
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\try\index.php(202): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#6 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\try\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php on line 92
```

Comment: Please explain how you configured the newly downloaded codeigniter .Then i can help you . May you hadn't yet configured it well. Edit your question.

Comment: please check pdo  driver library ...

Comment: Im using codeigniter 2.0 sir! coz i used 3.0 first but session is hard with 3.0 and when i used 2.0 its fine! but this doesnt work out in 2.0 i guess! why though? thanks alot

Answer (score 5):

It would be Great if you let know configuration used i.e. mysql version
php version,etc.

This error may be

1. Mysql extension is missing
2. Versioning issue that's depriciated function has been used by you.
3. $db['default']['dbdriver'] ='mysqli'; // use latest driver

I hope it clears to you.

Comment: Im using codeigniter 2.0 sir! coz i used 3.0 first but session is hard with 3.0 and when i used 2.0 its fine! but this doesnt work out in 2.0 i guess! why though? thanks alot

Comment: Yhea, please let us know php version? open xampp->click on shell-> type php -v. please try with this setting in database.php in config folder : $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';